# epspdfconversion error: 'pdftex.def Error: .... .... .pdf not found'

Tags: eps, epstopdf

I am using MikTex 2.9 and TexStudio on Windows 10.

1.I have included in my preamble:
\usepackage[outdir=./converted_pdfs/]{epspdfconversion}

2. In Configure TexStudio -> Commands -> PdfLateX, I have:
   pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 %.tex
3. I have a main .tex file in a directory 'XX', and I have a subdirectory 'XX/gfx' where I have stored my EPS vector graphics.

When trying to build I get:

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `./converted_pdfs/VTERM1042_WT_Spikes-epspdf-to.pdf' not found. ...th=0.8\textwidth]{VTERM1042_WT_Spikes.eps}
```

After searching a lot about the problem on the net I tend to think it is a problem of the path to the .tex file or the path to the .eps files. My impression from reading other people's posts is that "it" does not know where to look for the eps files.

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Did you test it work if you don't use the special outdir?

Comment: Yes, I just tried. It does not work. The problem is related to 'inability to find the correct path', while package epstopdf does not suffer from the same problem.

Comment: By the way, have I correctly enable the write18 option? is my syntax correct for Windows 10, MikTex 2.9 and TexStudio Configuration?

Comment: Yes you can use `--enable-write18`. `--shell-escape` works too. Beside I guess that you didn't read the documentation of epspdfconversion. It says for `outdir`: "For other directories ensure that they can be found.
See \graphicspath or TEXINPUTS."

Comment: Well, as a matter of fact, I have read that part of the documentation that you are referring to. However, I have tried with or without the 'outdir' and it still does not work.

Comment: So I took the trouble to make a test document and checked the log file. It says quite clearly " epspdf <file> is used to convert eps->pdf 
(not epstopdf (script)) " and a check in the docu showed "(Note the epsTOpdf vs epspdf).". The package needs epspdf which is not in miktex you can find here http://tex.aanhet.net/epspdf/.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer you are totally correct! It amazes me how this eludes so many people and eluded me too. But I would like a log message that points to the fact of the missing epspdf tools. Thanks a lot! You can post it as an answer so that we close the topic "formally".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took the trouble to make a test document and checked the log file. It says quite clearly

```
 epspdf <file> is used to convert eps->pdf (not epstopdf (script))
```

and a check in the docu showed `(Note the epsTOpdf vs epspdf)`.

The package needs epspdf which is not in miktex you can find here 
http://tex.aanhet.net/epspdf.

(This shows again how useful a full test document is, so that one can try out the problem and see the full log-file and don't have to rely on some snippets in the question).

Comment: Now I have positively installed the epspdf and tried if it works stand alone - yes it does. There is an executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\epspdf\epspdf\epspdftk.exe" which opens up a GUI window where you can select an .eps file and choose where to save the output .pdf file - it works beautifully. However in TexStudio it continues to return the error I mentioned initially. Where can I look for the possible cause?

Comment: is there a epspdf.exe, and is in the PATH?

Comment: No, there is no 'epspdf.exe' anywhere on my drive. There is a 'epspdftk.exe' which opens up a tool with a GUI that works and converts. Because 'epspdf.exe' cannot be found in my system, this means it is not in the windows installer downloaded from the webpage http://tex.aanhet.net/epspdf. I also downloaded the .zip archive which also does not contain a "epspdf.exe" file. It is possible that earlier version of epspdf which have been written in Ruby used the 'epspdf.exe' but the recent version which is not in Ruby does not have 'epspdf.exe'.

Comment: Well then you will probably have to create an epspdf.bat as described on the website.

Comment: It does not make sense, because in the .bat file , ruby is mentioned. I don't have ruby and ruby is not mentioned as a prerequisite for epspdf on the website.

Comment: I don't have the epspdf.rb mentioned in the bat file either. This is one big mess...

Comment: The website doesn't mention a rb-file, the newest version of epstopdf is based on lua (.tlu), and the bat should call `texlua "<path_to_epspdf.tlu>" %*`

Comment: I finally got it to work with the following script in a .bat file named epspdf.bat:

@ECHO OFF

set ScriptPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\epspdf"\epspdf
texlua %ScriptPath%\epspdf.tlu %*

There is only a small thing, the bat file execution (not pdflatex) returns an error:
"ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`epstopdf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) package instead? It is the package called by `epspdfconversion` and unless you are looking to pass specific parameters to `epstopdf`, you shouldn't need to use `epspdfconversion`.

Here is a setup I used earlier, that worked for me:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}
\graphicspath{{../}}
```

*Note the extra curly brackets inside the `graphicspath` command.*

I stored my images in a subfolder (`img`) relative to the `.tex` file (similar to your setup) and my EPS conversions were created in the same folder as the `.tex` file.

This meant I called my EPS's as follows:

```
\includegraphics{img/eps_name}
```

*Note that, as always, no `.eps` ending is required. In your case, you would replace `img` with `gfx` of course.*

I am using `texify` to compile but I don't think your command line should be a problem.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your input. I tried your suggestion and it works beautifully, with 'epstopdf' package. I also tried your approach with 'epspdfconversion' but it did not work. I tried it because the  "\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}" argument is described in the 'epspdfconversion' documentation also. The "graphicspath{{../}}" command, I suppose applies to graphics in general and not to 'epstopdf' particularly ? (I might be mistaken here).

I very much appreciate your answer, but because I want to get to the bottom of this, and enable the use of epspdfconversion package I will wait and hope.

Comment: I vaguely recall the `graphicspath` command being necessary in order for the compiler to find the PDFs created by the package, as these were created one folder level up (`../`) from the original image. I could be wrong, though, as this was a while ago.

Comment: The error and the problem that I have described, unfortunately, does not advance to the stage that you are describing. It is not the newly created PDFs that cannot be found but the .eps image. With the problem I am experiencing there is no PDF yet produced. This is in contrast with the use of 'epstopdf' package which works for me and I can choose where to place the newly created PDFs using 'outdir=./converted_pdfs/.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, obviously epspdf does not come with MikTeX and needs to be installed by all users of epspdfconversion that are using that distribution. I didn't know that (I am the author of epspdfconversion). I am assuming that a command

epspdf --GRAY afile.eps

can be called via write18/shell-escape

It seem that it is not yet clear how Windows/MikTeX-users make sure that this works.

Daniel